# predict an average price for properties with python

Tags: python, arrays, string, associative-array

I need to predict an average price for properties with a built area between 200 and 300 sq.m. and sea views** in January, February, March, April and May 2018. Using python or R. The problem is, I have a variation of views separated by comma in just on column, the sea views variations are like that (variations: ‘views to the sea'','sea view','seaview','ocean view','Water View','views to the beach','facing the sea','lake view','over the whole bay','views of the sea','over the bay','views of the bay','over the sea’,).

And the other point is that one property has changed its price 3x just in one year. I was trying to model using time series. But I have rethink about it. Could anyone give me some tips to solve that?

Comment: Please ask more specific questions, and add code, sample inputs and outputs.

Comment: This is in fact a good question, albeit on the wrong site. Can someone migrate this to Data Science Stack Exchange please.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the following features

- Area
- Month as categorical features (January = 1, February = 2, etc.)
- A n_gram or bag-of-words technique to vectorize the "sea view" column

I suggest this because evidently a sea view is more desirable than a lake view. And a beach view may also be disfavorable when compared to a sea view because it will attract crowds. So these cannot all be assumed to be the same. And I am guessing people will describe their properties all slightly differently, even though they mean the same thing.

## n_grams

**n-grams** is a feature extraction technique for language based data. It segments the Strings such that roots of words can be found, ignoring verb endings, pluralities etc...

The segmentation works as follows:

The String: Hello World

2-gram: "He", "el", "ll", "lo", "o ", " W", "Wo", "or", "rl", "ld" 
3-gram: "Hel", "ell", "llo", "lo ", "o W", " Wo", "Wor", "orl", "rld"
4-gram: "Hell", "ello", "llo ", "lo W", "o Wo", " Wor", "Worl", "orld"

## Bag-of-words

This creates a dictionary of words for example if your training data only contains the following words {beach, sea, view, lake, park, garbage, dump}. Then for you will create vectors which contain the frequency that each word appears. Then you will train this model and the model will learn which words best describes your output distribution.

Then in the future you vectorize the words in the same way and pass them through the model and you will get your desired output.